# How to find stored login name of MSN messenger with C# or VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, msn-messenger

I have multiple chat programs (e.g. **MSN**, **Yahoo** **Messenger**, ICQ etc.) where the login name is stored, and I only need to type in the password to log on to in. But it's a hassle to open each and every chat program then login.

So, I attempt to write an application where it fetches all these stored chat program's user name into one application under a single window/form (similar to meebo.com, but I'm doing a desktop app version). User can then login in to any chat program in one application.

The first step is: how can I get or where do I look for the stored user name of a chat program? I looked into **Credential Manager**, but it isn't helpful.

[EDIT] Please don't tell me to use existing software, I would like to write my own :)

Comment: use Pidgin :)  http://www.pidgin.im/

Comment: thanks. I know such things exist, but I would want to learn how to write one my own to understand how things work.

Comment: i hear you. i'm the same way. but i gotta plug good, free software when i get the chance.

Answer (score 1):

MSN Messenger stores the username and password in the Credentials Manager.
To access this, you can use the following API by Microsoft.

- [Credential Management with the .NET Framework 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/indonesia/msdn/credmgmt.aspx)

Comment: The document does not says how to access it, and none of the code compiles. I think it is something else. Please see my revised question.

Answer (score 0):

Spend hours reading Credential Management and find no solution - of may be I do not understand it. Found an easier way out just by reading the registry. It happens that login name of chatting program have their login name saved in the registry as a subkey folder.